# Is this attitude common or rude in western countries?

Tags: australia, culture

Our manager has recently changed. The new manager's attitude is weird. For example, a couple of times, I have seen that my colleagues ask her a question and in response she said:

> I don't know. This is your job

Or once one of my colleagues was explaining something to her. In the middle of the conversation she suddenly said:

> I know these. You don't need to explain it. I am too busy

And she left.

Is she rude or in western countries, is such an attitude common? I have to mention that I am a skilled migrant working in Australia.

Comment: Not common, unfortunately not rare.

Comment: What is she being asked?  If you asked me as a manager about a team related issue I should be able to answer.  If you wanted to discuss the best way to implement something in python I'd say "that's your job".  If you cornered me on the way to a meeting with the CEO I'd say "I am too busy", you need to explain it in context, otherwise it seems like a rant.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to say without actually seeing the event as it happened. Many employees are supposed to be better *at their job* then the manager would be.

If I had some software development problem (that's my job) and asked my manager, he would say "that's your job". He isn't supposed to be able to solve these problems. If I had a problem interacting with a colleague, or another team, then my manager should and would help because he is supposed to be better at these things than me.

Answer (score 0):

**Is she rude or in western countries such an attitude is common?**

It's difficult to say without much more clarification of the context. At first glance, I would say she's rude but that could be completely wrong. Cultural differences frequently cause misunderstandings. I'm in the USA. I once had a cultural difference cause a problem between myself and a person from a different region of my own country. From my own personal experience, I find people from some other parts of the world to be more polite than Americans and, on the other hand, I find other people from some other parts of the world to be less polite than Americans. So, it seems to vary from region to region and perspective to perspective...and even person to person. It's an extremely complex issue.